# Ember Octane - Mirage requestbody null

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-cli-mirage

I am newbie on ember.js, trying to do some tests with mirage. Only certain fields of model come true, but the others come as null. As I am a newbie, I am not sure if the reason is about these lines

Account.js

```
const accountId = this.args.account.id;
var data = this.store.createRecord('subscription', 
{
  id:1,
  accountId: accountId,
  startDate: Date.now(),
  endDate: Date.now()
});
data.save();
```

Mirage - Config.js

```
this.post('/subscriptions', (schema, request) => {
    let requestBody = JSON.parse(request.requestBody);
    schema.subscriptions.push(requestBody);
  }, {timing: 2000});
```

Comment: It's not clear what's the problem? What is null and what is not?

Comment: Hi, Sara. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Generally, it is helpful to put yourself in the shoes of someone who might want to help answer your question and give as much information and clarity as possible as to what is happening. Don't assume the problem is in one piece of code, try to give as much relevant code as you can. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to return something from the `this.post` route to get a response with data in it. There are some examples in [the documentation](https://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/versions/v0.4.x/defining-routes/#working-with-models) that may provide more detail for you.

In your example this may look like:

```js
this.post('/subscriptions', (schema, request) => {
    let requestBody = JSON.parse(request.requestBody);
    return schema.subscriptions.create(requestBody);
  }, {timing: 2000});
```

However this is going to depend a lot on how your application is configured. If you're using JSON:API it may require parsing the request slightly differently so more information about how your models and adapters are configured would make it easier to answer this question.